# Division by zero and undefined behaviour in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In [this paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/ub:apsys12.pdf) is the following example of a piece of code that can trigger a division-by-zero:

```
if (arg2 == 0)
    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_DIVISION_BY_ZERO),
                    errmsg("division by zero")));
/* No overflow is possible */
PG_RETURN_INT32((int32) arg1 / arg2);
```

`ereport` here is a macro that expands to a call to a `bool`-returning function `errstart` that may or may not return and, conditional (using a `?:`) on its return value, a call to another function.  In this case, I believe `ereport` with level `ERROR` unconditionally causes a `longjmp()` someplace else.

Consequently, a naive interpretation of the above code is that, if `arg2` is nonzero, the division will happen and the result will be returned, while, if `arg2` is zero, an error will be reported and the division will not happen.  However, the linked paper claims that a C compiler may legitimately hoist the division before the zero check, then infer that the zero check is never triggered.  Their only reasoning, which seems incorrect to me, is that

> [T]he programmer failed to inform the compiler that the call to ereport(ERROR, : : :) does not return. This implies that the division will always execute.

John Regehr has a [simpler example](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232):

```
void bar (void);
int a;
void foo3 (unsigned y, unsigned z)
{
  bar();
  a = y%z;
}
```

According to this blog post, clang hoists the modulo operation above the call to `bar`, and he shows some assembly code to prove it.

My understanding of C as it applies to these snippets was that

1. Functions that do not, or may not, return are well-formed in standard C, and declarations of such require no particular attributes, bells, or whistles.
2. The semantics of a call to a function that do not, or may not, return are well-defined, in particular by 6.5.2.2 "Function calls" in C99.
3. Since the `ereport` invocation is a full expression, there is a sequence point at the `;`.  Similarly, since the `bar` call in John Regehr's code is a full expression, there is a sequence point at the `;`.
4. There is consequently a sequence point between the `ereport` invocation or `bar` call
   and the division or modulo.
5. C compilers may not introduce undefined behaviour to programs that do not elicit undefined behaviour on their own.

These five points seem to be enough to conclude that the above division-by-zero test is correctly-written and that hoisting the modulo above the call to `bar` is incorrect.  Two compilers and a host of experts disagree.  What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: The assertion 'no overflow is possible' is wrong on 2's complement machines (most machines).  If you divide INT32_MIN by -1 and you get INT32_MAX+1, which is an overflow on the `int32` type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't know the range of input values for that first snippet.  That may be another issue, but I believe it's independent of the divide-by-zero case.

Comment: This looks like a close duplicate with better answers: [Are all functions in C/C++ assumed to return?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20059532/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: R's answer here is excellent.  I see longer answers at the other question, but no better answers.

Comment: normally when we have duplicates we want someone looking at one of them to be able to easily find the other one. Normally the criteria is [views, votes and completeness of answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277129/1708801) I personally believe the question linked above has a more diverse set of answers but I am happy to let someone else decide perhaps @MattMcNabb has a strong opinion here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paper is wrong, and as for the clang example, this is a compiler bug (a rather common occurrence with clang...). I wish I could give you better reasons, but you already provided all the correct reasoning in the question.

Actually, for the clang issue, as far as I can tell, no bug has been demonstrated yet. Since `bar` **does return** in the example on the blog you linked to, the compiler is free to reorder the division across the call. This is trivial to do if `bar` is defined in the same translation unit, but it's also possible with LTO. To actually test for this bug, you need a function `bar` that never returns.

Comment: How do you know that `bar` returns?  I see a declaration but no definition.

Comment: Well, it reproduces without a definition of `bar` here :)

Comment: OK, then you've confirmed it. I suspected the bug exists, but the blog does not clearly show it, and the inclusion of a function `bar` that *does* return muddles the issue.

Comment: As an aside, it is trivial to provide a definition of `bar()` that doesn't return in standard C: `void bar(void) { exit(0); }`.

Comment: @caf: I think I'd prefer `volatile int foo; void bar(void) { if (foo) exit(0); }`, since even a compiler which could see all code paths from `main()` would not be entitled to make any assumption about whether it would or would not return [other code in the system could find out where `foo` was located and modify it asynchronously without the compiler having any way of knowing about it, and the code would be required to honor such effect]

Answer (score 2):

Using the "as if" rule...

The division can be done wherever the compiler feels like it; as long as the resulting code behaves as if the division was done in the correct place.

This means that:

a) if division by zero (or division resulting in an overflow) causes an exception (e.g. typical for integer division on 80x86) then the division can't be done before the function call (unless the compiler can prove that the division is always safe).

b) if division by zero (or division resulting in an overflow) does not cause an exception (e.g. typical for floating point on 80x86) the compiler may do the division before the function call; as long as nothing in the function being called can modify the values used in the division.

Comment: The "as if" rule does not permit the compiler to generate code that crashes when the behaviour of the abstract machine is not undefined, unspecified, or implementation-defined.

Comment: @tmyklebu: It does, however, allow a compiler to generate code that performs operations (like division by zero) which would crash on *some platforms* in cases when the abstract machine operation is fully defined, *provided that the operations don't crash the platform on which the code will run*.

Comment: @tmyklebu we're off topic for this question, but AFAIK, it doesn't permit the compiler to generate code that crashes even in the case of unspecified behaviour, or implementation-defined (except for the case where raising a signal is a permitted form of implementation-definition).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I removed my answer since I found a close duplicate see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305296/division-by-zero-and-undefined-behaviour-in-c#comment51585033_18305296) and it has much better answers. I even commented on that one, it is amazing how many SO question you completely forget about. Seems like the answer can depend on whether we are talking about C or C++.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well they are different languages